RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
I am trying to get boolean outputs {0,1} for my neural network. My final output is a real value e.g. r and I wanted it to be 0 if r <= 0 and be 1 if r >1. To do this, I did the following code in my forward network:
def forward(self, x1, x2):
        ## encode ##
        x= self.encoding1(x1)
        #print(x.shape)
        y= self.encoding2(x2)
        s= x-y
        
        # Get batch_size
        batch_size = x.size(1)
        out = torch.zeros(batch_size, 1, device=x.device)
        # Loop over every value in batch
        for i in range(batch_size):
            s= x-y
            if s <= 0:
                out[i] = 0
          
            else:
                out[i] = 1
            print(out)
        return out

But in training, I get the following error:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-41ff6768dddb> in <module>
     19 
     20         #forward feeding batch of inputs
---> 21         outputs = model(x, y)
     22         #out= Label(outputs)
     23 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-29-6c18994c615a> in forward(self, x1, x2)
     98         for i in range(batch_size):
     99             s= x-y
--> 100             if s <= 0:
    101                 out[i] = 0
    102 

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous


I searched, found some explanations but did not get how to fix my error. My question is that how I should get my output as e.g. [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0] if my batch size is 8 to training my network?
Can anyone help me please and tell me how to define a forward to get such output?

This is probably because you are not indexing the x and y tensors, meaning that the s is not a single value but a tensor. The easiest way of converting the tensor from continuous values to 0/1 is using torch.where:
out = torch.where(s <= 0, 0, 1)

Do keep in mind though that this sets all values to zero if the value in the result is smaller than or equal to zero, and one for the rest (which matches with your code), which differs from what you describe in the text ("I wanted it to be 0 if r <= 0 and be 1 if r >1").

Thank you. But now I get the error: RuntimeError: "mse_cpu" not implemented for 'Long'. Do you know why I get this error?

I expect first casting to float/double will solve this issue: s.double()

Thank you very much. That helped me.
